# Show items to listview using post parameter in retrofit

Tags: android, json, list, post, retrofit2

I have been searching for a tutorial of retrofit several days. I have to show the items in listview using retrofit. It is done using post parameter. In volley, if we have any parameters to post we would do with hashmap like string request in volley. Here I have one parameter to post as form data to get response. How is it possible to show items in Listview by posting a parameter and receiving the response.The response is in JSON. Can anyone post some sample code? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You define a retrofit object and simply get a list of it.

So, Lets say you have an object User, which has an id and a name.

You define a RetrofitUser class

```
public class RetrofitUser {


    public static final String SERIALIZED_ID_NAME = "id_user";
    public static final String SERIALIZED_USERNAME = "name";

    @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_ID_NAME)
    private String mId;

    @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_USERNAME)
    private String mUserName;
}
```

Where the SERIALIZED values are the json key values.

You would then define an api like so

```
public interface UserApi {

    @GET("/{yourParam}")
    Call<List<RetrofitUser>> getUserWithParam(@Path("yourParam") String param);
}
```

You would then call the api -

```
mUsersService = retrofit.create(UserApi.class);
Call<List<RetrofitUser>> userCall = mUserService.getUserWithParam(yourParam);
        Response<List<RetrofitUser>> response;
        try {
            response = userCall.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (response.body() != null) {
             List<RetrofitUser> users = response.body();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("response body null");
        }
```

Now, assuming your JSON looks something like this

[{id_user:1, name:"johnny"}, {id_user:2, name:"jane"}]

you should be ok and get this is a list of RetrofitUsers with everything full.

Comment: How we can do with post request?